# Printing value of a optional variable includes the word "Optional" in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

.I am new to iOS and to Swift
In my application I'm trying to print an optional value and it prints "Optional(value of the variable)"
How do I remove this word **optional**

```
var bDay = StringUtils.convertDateToString(birthDate, format: Constants.BIRTHDAY_FORMAT)
let age = self.clientDetail?.getAge()
println("age.....\(age)")
bDay += "\(age)"
```

The output in the console is

```
age.....Optional(29)
```

I'm trying to assign this variable to a UILabel but on screen it shows up like 
**Sep 17, 1986 Optional(29)**

My objective is to remove this optional word and make it appear like
**Sep 17, 1986(29)**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Optional chaining is used here:

```
let age = self.clientDetail?.getAge()
```

So return of `getAge()` is optional value. Try optional binding:

```
if let age = age {
    println("age.....\(age)")
}
```

or simply unwrap the `age` with  `age!`, but this will crash your app if `age` is nil.

Comment: Using the forced unwrapping operator is discouraged without checking for nil first. It causes the app to crash if `age` is nil - I recommend updating your answer with an explicit mention about that

Comment: @Antonio It depends on the situation. If they where discouraged in any case the implicitly unwrapped optionals couldn't even be in the language. Sometimes its good to crash early.

Comment: @Kristeins The updated answer works for me :)

Comment: @Kirsteins: indiscriminate usage of the forced unwrapping is to be avoided unless for specific needs. There's a reason  if `clientDetail` is an optional: because it can be nil. Using `!` prints the correct string **OR** makes the app crash. I am just suggesting you to make that explicit, because it's really bad to misuse it. Once done, I'll remove my downvote

Comment: @Antonio If you don't want to unwrap optional without checking for the I guess its best to use optional bidding in every case as its more clearer in intent.

Comment: @Kirsteins Optional binding is one possible solution. What is important is that a potentially nil expression is guarded against forced unwrapping, whichever method is used to accomplish that. I think it's important to make that clear when answering to questions.

Comment: @Kirsteins How do I do optional binding 
for  priceLabel.text = "S \(meal.price)". Meal is a variable, Price a double.