# Swift Array is printing word "optional" from my array dont want to force unwrap

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My array: `var savedDataArray: Array<String>? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedDataArray") as? Array<String>`

console prints `Optional(["75500.0", "2.19351e+08"])` I do not want the word "optional" or the braces

Force unwrapping `var savedDataArray Array<String>!` stops the word "optional" appearing  however my array may be `nil` so dont I dont want to do this ( and the braces are still present)

This is not the same as the following answers as they all suggest foce unwrapping

[Printing value of a optional variable includes the word "Optional" in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733333/printing-value-of-a-optional-variable-includes-the-word-optional-in-swift)

How to print a string from plist without “Optional”?

Swift giving Optional(3) instead of 3 for .toInt

Comment: Actually many answers to the linked threads suggest *optional binding* and not *forced unwrapping* ...

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? This will only be visible in log, but not in the end product

Comment: @Cristian because the values will form the body of an email

Comment: @JSA986 But if you paste the values in a form or something like that, there shouldn't be an Optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print out an optional, you will always have `Optional(...)` in there. The only way to lose that is to unwrap. That's the only solution.

If you are worried about `nil` values, check for `nil` and then unwrap.

Comment: That answers that then.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can pass it to `println` as `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`:

```
var array1:[String]? = ["foo", "bar"]
var array2:[String]? = nil

println(array1) // -> Optional(["foo", "bar"])
println(array2) // -> nil
println(array1 as [String]!) // -> [foo, bar]
println(array2 as [String]!) // -> nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `??` like this if it's ok to see no difference between nil and an empty array.

```
var array: [String]? = ["A", "B"]
println(array ?? []) // Prints "[A, B]"
array = nil
println(array ?? []) // Prints "[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because it is an optional. You have to unwrap.

You can force unwrap:

```
println(myText!);
```

or check against a nil first

```
myText : String = myText ?? ""
println(myText)
```